Instaloader 400 Bad Request - "fail" status, message "feedback_required"
I am trying to use instaloader python module to fetch data from any Instagram profile by username, but I encounter a 400 Bad Request - "fail" status, message "feedback_required" error
400 Bad Request - "fail" status, message "feedback_required" when accessing https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query?query_hash=2b0673e0dc4580674a88d426fe00ea90&variables=%7B%22shortcode%22%3A%22BjA_hztgz8m%22%7D

Does anyone have a solution for this error?
import instaloader
import json

# Get instance with a custom user agent (desktop browser)
loader = instaloader.Instaloader()

# Set the user agent to mimic a desktop client
loader.context.user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"

# Load cookies from json file cookie.json that was exported manually
with open('cookie.json') as f:
    cookies_list = json.load(f)

session_data = {}
for cookie in cookies_list:
    session_data[cookie['name']] = cookie['value']

# Load session data from the cookies dictionary
username = "your_username"  # Replace with your Instagram username
loader.load_session(username, session_data)

# Use Profile class to access metadata of the account
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(loader.context, 'kevin')


print("Data saved to data.json")


Error 400 often indicates a locked account. In recent years, Instagram has done as lot to detect automated activities.
Log in to your account to see if you need to confirm that you are indeed a human.
